# It's correct xml markup?

Tags: xml

I have following xml:

```
<xml>
     <root>
     <catalog name="Main">
        <catalog name="Structure">
            <catalog name="Structure">
            </catalog>
            <file name="Структура" value="Structure.doc">
            </file>
              </catalog>
        <catalog name="Determine">
            <file name="Структура" value="Structure.doc" />
        </catalog>
     </catalog>
     <catalog name="NotMain">
     </catalog>
      </root>
</xml>
```

It's normal, that element catalog is contains other element catalog that contains catalog too?

Comment: You are using some unspecified data format that is expressed in XML. We don't know anything about that data format, so we can't tell you if it is right or not.

Comment: you would use such a thing? acceptably?

Comment: @andi my question: xml element can contain an xml element with the same name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

syntax correctness you can check with: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 2):

It could not be semantic but it's well formed IMHO

Answer (score 2):

I would add an xml-declaration, especially since you use some cyrillic characters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Perhaps that was what you intended when using the `<xml>`-tag that's around your `<root>`-tag.